# Implement a Timer in a Method

Tags: java

I am doing a project in Java (RPG-Game) and there is a method, called "sleep()", if the hero sleep he can't fight against enemys or others and if he has for example 1 HP after he slept he gets max HP and then he is ready to fight.
And my problem is that I need a timer for the sleep method, for example the Hero "Venus" sleeps for 3 Minutes and he can't fight in that time.

My attributes and my method:

```
public class Superhero {
private String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();;
private String name;
private int healthPointsMax;
private int healthPointsCurrent;
private int damage;
private int critStrike;
private int critChance;
private String heroRole;
private int experiencePoints;
private String superpowers;
private boolean readyToFight;
private boolean inFight;
private boolean alive;`
```

and my method:

```
public void sleep() {
    System.out.println("Dein Superheld " + name + " legt sich schlafen.");
    System.out.println(name + " hat wieder volle HP, wenn er/sie wach ist.");
    setHealthPointsCurrent(getHealthPointsMax());
    readyToFight = false;
}
```

Comment: Did you try anything yet as for the timer? I don't see anything related to that in your post.

Comment: maybe you ask your question also on https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do you want *nothing else* happen while the hero is sleeping or do you want the rest of the game to continue (with the restriction that they can't fight)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try using a java.util.Timer in your method as below :

```
public void sleep() {
    System.out.println("Dein Superheld " + name + " legt sich schlafen.");
    System.out.println(name + " hat wieder volle HP, wenn er/sie wach ist.");
    readyToFight = false;
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
         public void run() {
              setHealthPointsCurrent(getHealthPointsMax());
              readyToFight = true;
              timer.cancel();
         }
    };

    long delay = 120000L; // 2 minutes delay
    timer.schedule(task, delay);
}
```

Comment: Okay, Thanks I understand and if I write to long delay = 1000 would be that than 1 second? :/

Answer (score 0):

You can instanciate an actual Timer in Java. Check the documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html